# Where is an EASA PPL valid outside of Europe?

Tags: ppl, easa

I am considering obtaining an EASA PPL in the U.K. I would like to know where exactly in the world the license is recognized with little to no additional paperwork/training outside of Europe. Specifically I would like to know what is needed to fly in the Caribbean, Colombia or Chile with this license.

I am a complete aviation beginner so apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: It might also depend on where the aircraft you intend to fly is registered.

Comment: In general: [What is required for a pilot to fly in another country?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2845) Also related: [May I fly an aircraft registered in an EASA member with an EASA licence (NOT same country as airplane) outside Europe?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12220)

Comment: [This](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/62) is probably related; at least in the Caribbean many GA aircraft are US-registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the EASA PPL is valid worldwide, but you must check the local laws prior to fly, for example, here in Brazil to fly a Brazilian registrated airplane (PT-***) you shoud have an ANAC PPL license, but if you are flying to Brazil in an UK based Aircraft( reg. G-****), you can fly it with your EASA PPL.

If you intent to Fly a Non-European aircraft for a long period in a same country, you should validate your EASA license within the local Aviation Authority, that ensures that you get the same level of license as you have from EASA.