# Does my PPL need to be checked again when I move to another country?

Tags: ppl

If I acquire my PPL in one country and move to another one, is there any procedure to evaluate that PPL and get it in another country?

Did anyone have an experience with that? I'm interested in general rules, if any, and to know what would happen when moving from EU to USA or USA to EU, in particular.

Also, what about renting an airplane in another country? Would someone need to reevaluate my license?

Comment: It completely depends on where you live for the time being and were you want to move to. If you for example stay inside the European Union your PPL is still valid. Would you clarify your question by adding information about the locations?

Comment: First of all i wanted to know if there are some general rules... And, if someone have specific example what had happened in real world.

In particular, maybe it would be useful to know what would happen in EU to USA or USA to EU moving?

Comment: We have a few questions already on this, you could start with [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/62) for example.

Comment: @mariotanenbaum there are no general rules, except "check local authorities at your destination".

Comment: Most places won't rent you an aircraft unless you do a check ride with one of their guys first, regardless of your licence

Answer (score 0):

You have to take your logbook and your license to civil aviation of that country and then they will request a confirmation from the country that you have got your license from to be sure that if your license is still valid. After confirmation you have to join any ATO and undergo flight and ground training on the plane category that you have your licensee on (You might not need it but they must are the one who ask for an examiner for you and you can't apply by yourself) and then you must do the oral exam and also a flight test on your single engine type.Remember for converting any license, only your flight hours will be accepted and some of your exams and not your ppl flight test.In some countries you must also do 4 exams which mostly are Nav,Met,Hp,and Law but in some other countries can be only Law . It is depend to the rules of the country that you are willing to get you license new from .For us to EU you must only do the ppl law exam. All this Rules applied for a valid ppl license .Good Luck

Comment: Do you have any references to FAA regulations that support your answer?

Comment: I am saying that on my friend experience. We were together in a flight school and then he decided to leave go home after ppl and continue his aviation route in US. He was from US.

Comment: "For EU to US you must only do the ppl law exam..." Did you mean "for US to EU"? In the US, there is no law exam, and you can get a US PPL without any test if you hold a valid ICAO one.