# Are there countries where commercial flying can be conducted with a Mexican DGAC private pilot license?

Tags: pilot-certification

I have a Mexican DGAC licence. Can I work in other countries, or do I need to get another licence? (for example an FAA one if I want to work in the US)

Comment: Which country's DGAC do you mean (there are [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGAC))? We have a lot of questions about using a license from one country in another one, [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44681/62) might be relevant for you.

Comment: Mexico. I guess you get it the same way as if you had a EASA Licence so thanks!

Comment: In the US you can do certain commercial flying, such as glider towing, with an FAA license, but I don't believe you could with your Mexican license.

Answer (score -2):

No. If you want to make commercial activities, you need a commercial license.

I remind you the [definition of commercial flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/71/637)

Comment: This is not strictly true under FAA regulations. In the US, with an FAA private pilot certificate, certain commercial flying is authorized, for example glider towing.

Comment: @JWalters Glider towing is not defined as commercial flight!

Comment: The question you linked to isn't really relevant here: it's about how the CBP defines commercial flight, not how the FAA defines it.

Comment: @Pondlife it is an ICAO definition. It is the same worldwide.

Comment: That's good to know, I didn't realize it was an ICAO definition!

Comment: The FAA defines commercial flying as flying for compensation or hire, to potentially include towing gliders. I can point you to the pertinent LOIs if you need more convincing.

Comment: @JWalters yes, please.

Comment: See [Martindell (2009)](http://bit.ly/2z8YwKe) and [MacKenzie (2009)](http://bit.ly/2mOLcJe). The FAA defines commercial flying, in pertinent part, as: "any nonmilitary flying as a required crewmember [...] for which the crewmember is paid for his or her services." See also [14 CFR 61.113(g)](http://bit.ly/2Ajb7ii): `A private pilot [...] may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft towing a glider or unpowered ultralight vehicle.` See also [Umphres (2010)](http://bit.ly/2A1IMtJ): "§61.113(g) permits a private pilot to act as PIC for compensation or hire of an aircraft towing a glider".