# I have a European SPL EASA license - can I fly a Cessna 172 in the US?

Tags: easa

I have a European EASA SPL licence with 200 flight hours logged and would like to fly in the US. I understand that a few hours flight training with a US instructor due to differences of rules makes perfectly sense. I also understand that I need a TSA approval. 
My question is, will I be able to get a Foreign Private Pilot License issued and fly a Cessna 172?

Comment: Yes. But there some hoops to jump through. Check out this post. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/183/i-have-a-european-easa-license-what-do-i-need-to-do-to-be-allowed-to-fly-in-th/227#227