# Using a Foreign-based FAA license while getting permanent license

Tags: faa, easa, pilot-certification

I am an American Expat who got my EASA PPL(A) license while living abroad.  I am about to move back to the US and looking into a permanent conversion to an FAA license.

Per [I have a European EASA license - what do I need to do to be allowed to fly in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/183/i-have-a-european-easa-license-what-do-i-need-to-do-to-be-allowed-to-fly-in-th?rq=1)
 the best option seems to be re-taking the FAA tests.  Otherwise I would have to find an EASA examiner in the US to avoid my EASA license expiring (perhaps thats not as hard as I assume?).

My question is am I allowed to file/use for the foreign-based license while training for the full license?