# Can I get an FAA instrument rating if I hold a private certificate based on a foreign license?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, instrument-rating

I have an EASA PPL/Medical with VFR privileges only. I have an FAA license which is based upon the EASA license. I’ve lived in the US for 5 years and would like to obtain an IR. Can I get an FAA IR with FAA certificate being based on a foreign license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes. I got an FAA IR while holding a foreign-based private license and medical (South African in my case).

The information in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/70194/62) might be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks very much!